# Fill in form in PHP

Tags: php, forms

So I've had to make a simple phonebook in PHP, but right now it simply echos the text beneath the form, I however, want it to fill it in the form which says: Phonenumber  (When you type in the exact name of someone you it echos their phonenumber)

Here's the Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Naam: <br><input type="text" name="name" /><br>
Telefoonnummer: <br><input type="text" name="phonenumber" disabled />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and here's the PHP (I'm Dutch btw so some of the text is in Dutch):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
$formNaam = $_POST['name'];
$naamPersoon = array ("Ilja Clabbers","Piet Paulusma","Gerrit Zalm");
$telefoonNummer = array ("038-4699776","0568-121212","010-2311512");

        if(empty($formNaam)) {
            echo 'Vul een veld in.';
    }   else if ($formNaam == $naamPersoon[0]){
            echo "Het telefoonnummer van " . $naamPersoon[0] . " is " .$telefoonNummer[0];
    }   else if ($formNaam == $naamPersoon[1]){
            echo "Het telefoonnummer van " . $naamPersoon[1] . " is " .$telefoonNummer[1];
    }   else if ($formNaam == $naamPersoon[2]){
            echo "Het telefoonnummer van " . $naamPersoon[2] . " is " .$telefoonNummer[2];
    }   else {
            echo "Deze naam staat niet in het archief";
    } 
}
?>
```

So basically what I'd like to know is; How do you get the phonenumber belonging to a persons name to be shown in the Form where it says 'Telefoonnummer:'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neater solution would be to make a single associative array with key => value pairs:

```
$naamPersoon = array (
    "Ilja Clabbers" => "038-4699776",
    "Piet Paulusma" => "0568-121212",
    "Gerrit Zalm" => "010-2311512",
);
```

Then your code would be:

```
$phonenumber = '';
if (array_key_exists($formNaam, $naamPersoon)) {
    echo "Het telefoonnummer van " . $formNaam . " is " . $naamPersoon[$formNaam];
    $phonenumber = $naamPersoon[$formNaam];
} else {
    echo "Deze naam staat niet in het archief";
}
```

Alternatively you could keep your two arrays as they are and use `array_search` to find the index of the name in the first array, then use it as the index you check in the second array

```
$phonenumber = '';
$index = array_search($formNaam, $naamPersoon);
if ($index === false) {
    echo "Deze naam staat niet in het archief";
} else {
    echo "Het telefoonnummer van " . $formNaam . " is " . $telefoonNummer[$index];
    $phonenumber = $telefoonNummer[$index];
}
```

---

Either way you can then use the assigned variable `$phonenumber` to add the number to the form by echoing it out as the input's value. At which point you can take out the `echo`s if you wish.

```
<form action="" method="post">
Naam: <br><input type="text" name="name" /><br>
Telefoonnummer: <br><input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($phonenumber)?>" disabled />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however, when I fill in                      value="<?=htmlspecialchars($phonenumber)?>"      it keeps saying it's an undefined variable even tho I've made the variable.